# Angular2 exception: Token must be defined

Tags: angular

app/boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{title}}'
})
class AppComponent {
  title: "app"
}
```

Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Token must be defined!
STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514
ExceptionHandler.call                 @ angular2.dev.js:1147
(anonymous function)                  @ angular2.dev.js:14801
NgZone._notifyOnError                 @ angular2.dev.js:5796
collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700
run                                   @ angular2-polyfills.js:141
(anonymous function)                  @ angular2.dev.js:5719
NgZone.run                            @ angular2.dev.js:5681
ApplicationRef_.bootstrap             @ angular2.dev.js:14906
bootstrap                             @ angular2.dev.js:25054
execute                               @ boot.ts:4
u                                     @ system.src.js:4597
execute                               @ system.src.js:4597
y                                     @ system.src.js:4597
...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is another error that has caught me multiple times.  I forgot (once again) to export my root component.  It should be:

```
export class AppComponent {
```

If I taken the time to look just a bit more closely at the stack trace (instead of searching StackOverflow and not finding my exact problem), I would have noticed that it referenced one of the files I wrote, `boot.ts:4`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case that was just because of semi-colon at the end of following line:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

Comment: They've changed this since the release candidate(s).  Now it is:


`import { Component } from "@angular/core";`

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone else coming here looking for any light with this very general error message, I was receiving this message from one of my test spec files because there was a mock service defined at the bottom of the same spec file, just moved it to the top (before the test definition) and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: To add to this, I had a typo on service I was injecting in a before hook, After fixing that things continued to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do make sure AppComponent was passed into the bootstrap function in my main.ts:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all these entries, also check for Typo Errors *App* instead of *AppComponent* etc

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = "World";
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue as well. In my case, it was because of the Augury extension, which was throwing because I've had Angular 2.1.3 and it supports 2.3.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an error with TestBed.get()
I was using wrong dependency name as the parameter.

```
let xyzService;

xyzService = TestBed.get(xyzService);

//Changing the above statement with xyzService = TestBed.get(XYZService); worked
```

It was a very silly mistake xD

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2023

Not sure if this will help anyone, this happened to me in a `angular-ssr` project with `nest-js` + `universal` + `angular`. I created a new service called `ConfigService` which was available on `nestjs` as well as `@angular/common`. I checked the import, it was correctly importing from `@angular/common` only. But I just renamed my service from

```
configService -> appConfigService
```

and the problem had been resolved.